# No Sound On Intel ich6M hd Audio(alc880) with intergrated Conexant modem

Tags: sound, realtek

OK, so I'm facing this frustrating problem for a long time

I just can't get the sound working on my Asus W5G00AE with Intel HD Audio(Intel HDA) 
that features a Realtek ALC880 Chipset and with a Conexant modem integrated in it
(well I just don't know why intel would integrate a modem with a sound card?).

I've tried a lot of solutions on the web,and none of them worked.

These are the things I tried:

1. Changing the model in `/etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf` to `auto`, `asus`, `asus-dig`, `asus-dig2`, `3stack`, `6stack`, and only when I changed it into `3stack`, alsamixer can get my soundcard, and the desktop volume control will get the output device,not the dummy output
2. Purging the `alsa-base` and `pulseaudio` package with the apt-get purge command:

   ```
   apt-get remove --purge alsa-base
   apt-get remove --purge pulseaudio
   ```

   This didnt work,either
3. Using the `pavucontrol` package:

   Well when I use this to monitor the output status,I can see rhythmbox playing music and the output volume bar is changing normally,but I still didn't hear any sound coming out of my laptop's speakers but the funny thing is , my intergrated microphone is working normally since I can see the input dB bar change when I tap it
4. Unmuting using `alsamixer`:

   All sound channels are unmuted,didn't work too

Thats all I've tried. Any other suggestions??

Here's my alsa info: [ALSA.org](http://www.alsa-project.org/db/?f=2a0bea1c6a6823c48b8f9f25f98df36ead90d8a9)

[pulseaudio --dump-conf](http://pastebin.com/q3EpgZpD)

pacmd dump-volumes:   pastebin.com/DF0a7bvK
  
pactl info:   pastebin.com/xTP77kjC

Comment: This may seem like a dumb question, but it happens a lot. Are you sure you have the correct output device selected? In my case i didn't pay attention to the device outputs and i was trying to get my sound card to work but my sound was running through hdmi and i forgot i set it up like that on windows when i installed Ubuntu. My sound goes from hdmi, to tv, and then to reciever.

Comment: Please, edit your post and include the following information: `amixer`, `pacmd dump-volumes`, `pactl info`, `pulseaudio --dump-conf` and if `pulseaudio --check`, this last one if finds no problems don't do anything.

Comment: There is only two output sections avaliable:analog output,analog-output-headphones,and no matter which output i select,there's no sound,including from the earphone jack and the speakers

Comment: The specs i see is that it's AC97, which means realtek. Realtek has linux drivers, have tried that? 

http://www.realtek.com.tw/downloads/downloadsView.aspx?Langid=1&PNid=23&PFid=23&Level=4&Conn=3&DownTypeID=3&GetDown=false#AC

Comment: tried already,didn't work,and it's a high definition audio codec,not ac97

Comment: Also, considering the age of this laptop, it's possible you may need to downgrade to a different version of ubuntu. I had a desktop from 2002 that would not work with ubuntu past 10.04

Comment: ok,i'll try 10.04 then.

Comment: 10.10 can be found here. Try a live cd and see if audio works. http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/10.10/ and 8.04 LTS in case 10.10 doesn't work http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/hardy/

Comment: well,both didn't work

Comment: I'm sorry then i'm out of idea's. Maybe your laptop is one of the unlucky machines that just isn't compatible.